# роутинг mvc 5 не получается вызвать метод

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Основные методы моего контроллера вызываются в виде:

```
controller/action?param1=12345&param2=test
```

сейчас возникла необходимость вызвать в виде:

```
controller/action/param1
```

Файл `RouteConfig.cs`:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
   routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
   routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
   routes.MapRoute(name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new {
        controller = "User", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional
    });
}
```

Метод, который нужно вызывать:

```
[Route("User/Delete/{id}")]
public string Delete(int id)
{
    // код
}
```

Соответственно, вызываю `/User/Delete/12345`, получаю 404 ошибку. Что здесь не так?

Comment: Всё так, ищите опечатку или иную проблему (переключите дебаг/релиз например). Специально проверил - у меня не воспроизводится.

Comment: Кстати. Зачем вам атрибут Route, если у вас уже есть подходящий маршрут? Он избыточен, просто закомментируйте его и будет по-прежнему продолжать работать, как и ранее.

Comment: `вызываю /User/Delete/12345` - метод какой используете? GET? DELETE? Оба не работают?

Comment: @AK, добавил  явно атрибут. сейчас получается вызвать только в виде querystring

Answer (score 2):

У вас код правильный. Проверяется крайне легко: создаём пустой проект и добавляем контроллер с вашим кодом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Маршруты в дефолтном приложении такие же как у вас:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Контроллер тривиальный:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        //[Route("User/Delete/{id}")]
        public string Delete(int id)
        {
            return id.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Так что ищите опечатку.